# new domain of integration under a change of variables

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the domain of integration in variables $t,s$ on $[0,T] \times [0,T]$. Then how do we find the domain of integration for the variables $u,v$ under the change of variables $u=t-s,v=t+s$? I am given that it becomes $[-T,T] \times [|u|,2T-|u|]$, but I don't know how to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often helpful to make a picture especially if the transformation is a linear one.

You can describe your coordinate transformation using a matrix:

- $\begin{pmatrix}u \\ v\end{pmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}}_{A=}\begin{pmatrix}t \\ s\end{pmatrix}$

So, the square $[0,T]\times [0,T]$ is mapped onto the diamond shape shown in the picture below. You can find this shape just by mapping the vertices:

- $A\begin{pmatrix}T \\ 0\end{pmatrix}= TA\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}T \\ T\end{pmatrix}$

Similarly you get the other vertices (see the picture)

- $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2T\end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix}-T \\ T\end{pmatrix}$

Now, the diamond shape is parametrized by $-T \leq u \leq T$ and $v$ lies between the graphs of $v=|u|$ and $v= 2T-|u|$. Hence,

$$-T \leq u \leq T, |u| \leq v \leq 2T-|u|$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $t,s \in [0,T]$. Note that $t=\frac {u+v} 2$ and $s=\frac {v-u} 2$. Hence $u+v \geq 0$ and $v-u \geq 0$. This gives $v \geq u$ and $v \geq -u$ so $v \geq |u|$. Also, $u+v \leq 2T$ and $u-v \leq 2T$. So $v \leq 2T-u$ and $v \leq 2T+u$. These two imply that $v \leq 2T-|u|$.

Now I leave it to you to start with  $u,v$ such that $v \geq |u|$ and $v \leq 2T-|u|$ and deduce that $t=\frac {u+v} 2$ and $s=\frac {v-u} 2$ both belong to $[0,T]$.

Comment: We should have $s=(v-u)/2$?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Right. Corrected my answer.